# How to change option value using button and send data to url?

Tags: web, get

I have this roll menu:

```
<form class="woocommerce-ordering" method="get">
<select name="orderby" class="orderby">
<option value="menu_order" >Default sorting</option>
<option value="popularity"  selected='selected'>Sort by popularity</option>
<option value="rating" >Sort by average rating</option>
<option value="date" >Sort by newness</option>
<option value="price" >Sort by price: low to high</option>
<option value="price-desc" >Sort by price: high to low</option>    
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="attest" value="true" /></form>
```

and I need it to change value using buttons. How can I send data to url for example "Sort by price: low to high" only by using button?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

If you want real submit buttons, you could use

```
<input type="submit" name="orderby[menu_order]" value="Default sorting">
<input type="submit" name="orderby[popularity]" value="Sort by popularity">
```

and then get the value using `key($_GET['orderby'])` (after other checks like does the value exist at all, is it an array, etc.)

---

**UPDATE:**

> My url should be looking like this, after sorting by price:
>
> `http://example.com/folder/?orderby=price&attest=true`

With pure HTML (and no server-side changes to the parameter processing), you can only get the `orderby=price` in your query string when using `input type=submit` buttons, when you are willing to set the parameter value as *displayed value* (`value=`) as well.

You could switch to `button` elements instead,

```
<button type="submit" name="orderby"
  value="price">Sort by price: low to high</button>
```

But be warned, support for this in older browsers (esp. IE <= 6, I think) is bad.

With pure links, if the value `attest=true` is known beforehand (from last form submit), you could build it into the URLs dynamically server-side already,

```
<a href="?orderby=price&attest=true">Sort by price: low to high</a>
```

(And then format those links to look like “buttons” with CSS.)

But that way, you could not pass any other additional parameters the user might want to select (if your form offers other options to change/select as well).

If you want anything more – then you will have to use JavaScript or must be willing to adapt your server-side parameter processing (the later could be done using `mod_rewrite` maybe, if you don’t want to manipulate actual script code).

Comment: MY url should be looking like this, after sorting by price: http://myweb.com/folder/?orderby=price&attest=true

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you meant, but if you wish to update data as soon as the user clicks an option in the dropdown menu, this jquery code will do the trick:

```
$('.orderby').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    alert(value);

    /*
    Run ajax here to make a call to a php script that
    takes the value parameter and returns the data in
    the correct order
    */
});
```